# What is the name of the device like thin client?

Tags: windows, networking, remote-desktop

I know that thin client for working with server is a small box to which you connect monitor, mouse, keyboard. Thin client via network connects to server and you can work in remote windows desktop. Thin client has a little memory and CPU to run soft to allow connecting to windows desktop. So using thin client all the users work on the server - it is easy to admin.

I was in one organization and I saw some device. It had about 8 connections for monitors, mouses and keyboards. As I was told this device allows to connect 8 users to work on the server. What is the name of such device and how all such solution works?

Comment: @JakeGould No, I don't have picture. The size of the device is like a home router.

Answer (score 2):

Got it!

What you saw is a special kind of KVM Switch, that [operates in reverse](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/KVM_switch#KVM_sharing_devices). So a single computer or server can be connected to multiple monitors, and controlled via multiple keyboards and mice:

[image: Reverse KVM Switch Diagram]

Answer (score 0):

Were more than one user able to use the system at a time?

It may have been a special MultiPoint system. This system allows multiple physical user sessions as opposed to one physical session and several remote sessions.

You can either hook up the monitors & input devices directly to the server or to a special device, one of which is called a USB thin client. [[more]](http://plugable.com/products/dc-125)

Additional information on MultiPoint can be found on Microsoft's website via [this link](http://www.microsoft.com/windows/multipoint/howitworks.aspx).